# How To Fix Firebase Realtime Database v9 push method

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, forms, firebase-realtime-database

I have made a **HTML** file `test.html` , but after submitting it, it doesn't show any data.
Am I doing something wrong, please assist me.

Am using Firebase Realtime Database v9

**CODE**

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="module">
     import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';

  import { getDatabase } from "firebase/database";

  const firebaseConfig = {
   apiKey: "*",
   authDomain: "*.firebaseapp.com",
   databaseURL: "https://*.firebaseio.com",
   storageBucket: "*.appspot.com"
  };

  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

  const database = getDatabase(app);

  import { getDatabase, ref, push } from "firebase/database";

  function writeMessageData() {
      const db = getDatabase();
    
      set(ref(db, 'data/'), {
          name: document.getElementById("feildName").value,
          msg: document.getElementById("feildMessage").value
      });
  }
    </script>
     <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="feildName" placeholder="Name">
        <input type="text" id="feildMessage" placeholder="Message">
        <button id="btnSubmit" onclick="writeMessageData()">SEND</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you try making the function async and adding an await before `set()`? Also what happens when you click the button like does the page refresh or anything?

Comment: The code looks fine at first glance. When you step through this code in a debugger, which is the first line of the code in your question doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Answer (score 0):

make your function async

```
async function writeMessageData() {
await set(ref(db,'ThePath'),{
 name: document.getElementById("feildName").value,
 msg: document.getElementById("feildMessage").value
}).then((success) => {console.log(success)}).catch((err) => {console.log(err)})
}
```

1. also check the database rules which you have set.
2. try removing the slash. change the path from `"data/"` to `"data"`

mostly it should work good luck.